# How to access an indexed string from a string collection saved in settings?

Tags: c#, string, syntax, settings, stringcollection

I have a few arrays of strings in my settings labelled meas1, meas2, meas3 etc...

If I want to set the 6th item in each string collection to "", how would I do that? Below is my broken code of  failed attempt:

```
for (int i = 19; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default["meas" + i][5] = "";
}
```

I know I could do `Properties.Settings.Default.meas1[5] = "";` but I want I have a lot of meas that I need to do so a for loop would be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe passing the item name and casting result to `StringCollection` would help:

```
for (int i = 19; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var prop = Properties.Settings.Default["meas" + i] as StringCollection;
    prop[5] = "";
}
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

You need to replace `as string[]` with your exact data type. But the above solves your issue of accessing the item by name.

Comment: can you expand a bit on what you mean by "You need to replace as string[] with your exact data type.". Isn't it string?

Comment: What is the exact type of your settings value ? Custom array of string ? Or a normal `StringCollection` ?

Comment: Normal `StringCollection`

Comment: @J.Doe Do you have problems with the above edited answer ?

Comment: error converting settings property to string collection :( Fixed it by removing properties so you're left with: `var prop = Properties.Settings.Default["meas" + i] as System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`

Comment: @J.Doe I just tried the above code and it works. Are you sure you defined the system settings are `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`.. Can you edit your question and show how do you define your settings ?

Comment: Yup work for me now just the properties was throwing it off